# Spring Integration XML Configuration and Spring Boot Java Annotation Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Is it possible to have spring integration xml configuration and spring boot java annotation configuration at the same time? Can you please refer with an example on this?
What is the best practice for this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, as explained in the spring documentation just use `@ImportResource` to import and XML configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marten pointed out it is fully fine to combine Spring Boot with an XML configuration. See Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.configuration-classes.importing-xml-configuration

> If you absolutely must use XML based configuration, we recommend that you still start with a `@Configuration` class. You can then use an `@ImportResource` annotation to load XML configuration files.

And here is the sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-xml/src/test/java/smoketest/xml/SampleSpringXmlPlaceholderBeanDefinitionTests.java